# How to open save file dialog in nodejs cli application

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, savefiledialog

I'm trying to create a nodejs cli. And I want to open save file dialog which returns the directory and filename after user interacts with it.

Thanks :)

Comment: "cli" doesn't open dialogs. you mean something like `scanf` ?   Otherwise maybe you want to look into electron

Comment: Do i need to use electron for dialogs?

Comment: Node was not designt to develop graphical applications, like open a "save as" dialog.

Comment: With any third party libraries, is it possible?

Comment: Anything is possible. You can call PowerShell on windows from Node.js and do it that way if you really want